# Insert a non-input row into a Formtasic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I am using Formtastic 2.1.1 in Rails 3.2 (with Active Admin) and I want to insert a row into my form that does **not** have an input field present. Is this possible and what is the syntax in the Formtastic DSL to achieve this?

Here's an example:

```
form do |f|

    f.inputs "Model Info" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :published
      f.input :path
    end

end
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
form do |f|

    f.inputs "Model Info" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :published
      f.input :path
      f.div "This is some important text that people using this form need to know"
    end

end
```

Has anyone done this with Formtastic before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To insert any custom code in *any* place, you may use `f.form_buffers.last`:

```ruby
form do |f|
  f.form_buffers.last << "<p>Hello world!</p>".html_safe # The simple way

  ft = f.template # just a helper variable

  f.inputs "Foo" do
    f.input :title

    f.form_buffers.last << ft.content_tag(:li) do
      ft.content_tag(:p, "Hello again!") +
          ft.tag(:input, type: :hidden, name: "bar[]", value: "baz")
    end
    f.input :path
  end
end
```

Just be careful about the HTML structure. If you call this from `f.inputs` block, your code will be placed inside an `<ol>` element. On the "form" level, you are inside a `<form>` element.

**A little warning:** As with any "undocumented feature" this method may change without warning in any new release.

Comment: How do I embed other content_tags in the <p>?

Comment: You can call `content_tag(:span,...) {...}` inside the `do..end` block of `<p>`. I do not remember exactly _(poor memory and no possibility to test it right now)_, but I suppose that you just add (`+`) few invocations of `content_tag` to create siblings (like when you need two spans inside a `<p>`)

Comment: First method is very helpful and would deserve addition as a helper method to active admin. Read only rows without the backing input field seem like a no brainer...

Comment: `form_buffers` is deprecated by version of Formtastic used in latest Active Admin release.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3834#issuecomment-93678418) on the related github issue describes a solution for that deprecation.

Comment: One liner to add text to the form ```li "Your text here"```. Check Horatio's answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755908/2765277

Answer (score 25):

Figured this out myself. I just needed to insert the html without any method calls, like so:

```
form do |f|

  f.inputs "Model Info" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :published
    f.input :path
  end

  f.inputs "Custom HTML Stuff" do
    "<div id=\"element-name\">
      Some kind of content
    </div>".html_safe
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

IDK if this is still something people search for but it was for me. Since `form_buffers` has been deprecated, I did the following and it worked out beautifully (with some CSS help).

```
form do |f|

  f.inputs "Model Info" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :published
    f.input :path
    li "Your important text here", class: "some_class"
  end
end
```

this outputs:

```
<li class="some_class">
  Your important text here
</li>
```

Got this idea from the docs after a too long Google search here
[FORMS](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md) and here [ARBRE](https://activeadmin.github.io/arbre/).

Answer (score 3):

**Here's a slightly simplified form of @arsen7's answer:**

```
f.form_buffers.last << 
  "<p>Activate interlock, dynatherms connected</p>".html_safe
```

which in my form looks like this:

[image: Simple HTML insert]

**And here's one that mimics ActiveAdmin's default style:**

```
f.form_buffers.last << (<<END
<li class="string input optional stringish">
  <label class="label">Activate interlock</label>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">Dynatherms connected</div>
</li>
END
).html_safe
```

which looks like this:

[image: ActiveAdmin-style HTML insert]

Comment: Wow, someone else used Voltron phr--- oh, it's me.