# ActiveAdmin display default view content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am working with ActiveAdmin and need to make customizations to some views and have come across a couple of scenarios I feel I am doing wrong.

I am adding an additional table to a show view (comments on Posts). This requires me to rewrite the whole attributes table and then add my panel. Is there a way to customize views without losing the default content?

I would also like to add a table of associated items on the show view which doesn't need to be customized is there any way to include the default tale that would normally be on the index view with default actions and paging?

Comment: This question is lacking specifics like existing code that asker has tried, better open a new one

Comment: @Cristian: It would've been better to open a new question for this, rather than editing this person's.

Comment: @Ryan I've only added a tag, otherwise I have exactly the same question.

Answer (score 36):

After digging in the [source code of Active Admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb), I've found a way to patch this

```
  show do
    default_main_content
    panel "Your Added Stuff" do
      # Add stuff here
    end
  end
```

Of course this is undocumented and maybe considered a hack, but unless any other solution exists, it works.

Note: To do this in the form action (new and edit):

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs
    # Other inputs here

    f.actions
  end
```

Comment: This is great! However, your "new and edit" workaround only works if you're inserting non-standard *inputs*. What if you want to add a div or paragraph tag? Unfortunately, you will not be able to do this with the ActiveAdmin DSL (so far as I know)... but you can insert arbitrary HTML via formtastic. 


**[Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524012/insert-a-non-input-row-into-a-formtasic-form)**.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using `default_main_content`, you could also just loop through the columns on the model like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Ad do
  show do
    attributes_table do
      default_attribute_table_rows.each do |field|
        row field
      end

      # Custom bits here

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple areas of the documentation might help you:

1. See [Customize the Show Page](http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html), [Customizing the Index Page](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html), [Customizing the Form](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html), and [Custom Pages](http://activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html). An example of customizing a show screen:

   ```
   ActiveAdmin.register Ad do
     show do |ad|
       default_main_content
       h3 ad.title
     end
   end
   ```
2. See **Custom Action Items** in the [Custom Controller Actions](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html) section of the documentation. An example:

   ```
   action_item :only => :show, :if => proc{ current_admin_user.super_admin? } do
        "Only display this to super admins on the show screen"
   end
   ```

**NB** `default_main_content` does not exist in the documentation anymore, yet it works fine.

Comment: Anything that you specify in the `show do ...` block is replacing all the default actions that Active Admin automatically built. So if you just want to add an extra field, you're stuck to do the whole page from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Just figured that out myself:
For the default table index page you can do something like this

```
index do
  h1 "Hello World"
  p "get more content"

  instance_eval(&default_table)
end
```

Comment: Oh this is nice, I didn't even know about this `default_table` method, thanks!