# Insert static content or some erb in activeadmin in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Trying to render some information about the object in active admin:

```
  f.inputs 'Devices' do
    f.has_many :devices, new_record: false do |device|
     "html or some ERB goes here"  

      device.input :status_activated, as: :bool
    end
  end
```

I've tried the following, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524012/insert-a-non-input-row-into-a-formtasic-form):

```
device.form_buffers.last << (<<END
<li class="string input optional stringish">
  <label class="label">Activate interlock</label>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">Dynatherms connected</div>
</li>
END
).html_safe
```

without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some simple HTML only, just do

```
f.inputs 'Devices' do
    f.has_many :devices, new_record: false do |device|
      span "html or some ERB goes here"  

      device.input :status_activated, as: :bool
    end
end
```

However, if you need something more complex, you're better off just extracting a partial, as in replace the `form do` block with `form partial: 'form'` and put your form layout and data in a `_form.html.erb` file in `app/views/admin/...`

Answer (score 2):

```
insert_tag(Arbre::HTML::Div) { content_tag(:span, "foo") }
```

Seems to be answered (but not accepted) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767245/1772830).

See the [arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre) repo for more info.